# could cocos2d-x use plist file to load box2D shape?

Tags: plist, box2d, shapes, cocos2d-x

I have a problem in cocos2dx. I just want to load a physics shape in box2d.How can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible.

Try this one

```
http://www.physicseditor.de/cocos2d-box2d/
```

Comment: This is, however cocos2d-x does not support the plist to define the shape.Do you have any other solution?